# DLL to LIB - Can´t open LIB file with JNI and System.load call

Tags: java, c++, visual-studio-2010, dll, shared-libraries

I´m using Visual Studio 2010 to create a DLL file and woks fine with the code bellow:

```
System.load("c:\\sharedFiles\\dll\\VisualDLL.dll");
```

Now I need the library to be static, because I can not install on the other machine the other libraries what I used when I created the DLL and so I need to come all in one package. After compile the same code to a lib, my application call the method bellow:

```
System.load("c:\\sharedFiles\\dll\\VisualDLL.lib");
```

But the following error appeared after creating .LIB create a file with Visual Studio 2010 to run the application appears:

c:\sharedFiles\dll\VisualDLL.dll: %1 is not valid Win32 application

The version of java is 1.7.09 64bits and Visual Studio it's compiling to 64bit machine target.

what happened? I cannot load lib file with this approach?

Comment: (a bit late comment) Well, what `System.load` does, is _dynamic loading._ Therefore it will only load dynamic libraries (DLLs in Windows).

Answer (score 2):

When you use an external DLL, you have an *import* LIB. The import lib is a stub, and your program or DLL will use it when linking to the external DLL. That is, its used when compiling and link you program or DLL to an external library.

A *static* LIB is a bit different. Its not a stub, and it carries around all the code that is needed. Its like a Linux archive, and your program or DLL would link directly to it.

If you are trying to have Java load you static lib VisualDLL.lib, then that won't work.

---

> Now I need the library to be static, because ...

No, it does not work like that. You need to build a wrapper DLL around your static lib. Java will then load your DLL when needed.

Comment: tks for your comments. It´s very useful. But I have no ideia how this work. Do you have some reference to share?

Comment: Well, you can read about Library Linking on Windows in Jeffrey Richter's [Programming Applications for Microsoft Windows](http://www.amazon.com/dp/1572319968). You can read about JNI in Sheng Liang's [The Java Native Interface: Programmer's Guide and Specification](http://www.amazon.com/dp/0201325772). Those are the two books I use. Each are listed on Amazon for a penny (literally $0.01). They will just cost you $3 or $4 shipping. That's a heck of a deal.